# SQL displaying details from 4 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

My aim is to have a SQL query that shows details of session - id, suburb of the branch the session is scheduled for, name of the movie, screen capacity and the session date. only sessions scheduled on 3rd or 13th of May

```
SELECT DISTINCT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCH.BRANCHSUBURB, MOVIENAME, SCREENCAPACITY, SESSIONDATE
FROM  SESSIONS, SCREEN, BRANCH, MOVIE
WHERE SESSIONDATE = '3-MAY-2016'
OR SESSIONDATE = '13-MAY-2016';
```

this does not do exactly what I want as there is ALOT more data displayed that I have.

The table setup is in the picture below.
[click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOThb.png)

Comment: Have a look at inner joins in SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback guys, I will look into SQL more as I am extremely new to it. Thanks for the heads up Gordon, will use your advice  on wards from today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use inner join to get desired result instead of Distinct keyword here.

Try this

```
SELECT b.BRANCHID, b.BRANCHSUBURB, m.MOVIENAME, sc.SCREENCAPACITY, se.SESSIONDATE
FROM  SESSIONS se INNER JOIN SCREEN sc on se.SCREENID = sc.SCREENID
INNER JOIN BRANCH b ON b.BRANCHID = se.BRNACHID
INNER JOIN MOVIE m ON m.MOVIEID = se.MOVIEID
WHERE se.SESSIONDATE BETWEEN '3-MAY-2016' AND '13-MAY-2016';
```

Comment: @Dan If it resolves your query please mark it as answer.